# How is the @ sign working in this command?

Tags: bash, localhost, daemon, tcpserver

I was working through this [guide](http://www.bytereef.org/howto/djb/daytime-server.html) to setup a daytime service. Near the end of the guide, after starting the service, it lists the command

```
date@ 127.0.0.1
```

This returns the current date and time, which is awesome! But how does it do that? I've never seen that syntax before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of ucspi-tcp that you [installed earlier](http://www.bytereef.org/howto/djb/ucspi-tcp-install.html).

> The ucspi-tcp package contains tcpserver, tcprules, tcprulescheck, argv0, fixcrio, recordio, rblsmtpd, tcpclient, who@, date@, finger@, http@, tcpcat, mconnect, addcr and delcr

Comment: I was being silly I guess.
`date@` is a legit command on its own:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/date@.1.html